# BizTalk Migration Issue from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Our team right now is upgrading our BizTalk 2009 server to 2010 and one of the process we need to undertake is to convert our codes from .Net Framework 2.0 to 4.0, but when we tried to test the newly converted codes, we hit this error that was not encountered when we are still using .Net Framework 2.0.

> A message received by adapter "FILE" on receive location RL.CMSO.CHTR.WebService.SubmitOrder" with URI D:\Data\CMSO\CHTR\WebService\Retry\SubmitOrder*.xml" is suspended.
>
> Error details: There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: CMSO.CHTR.Pipelines.ReceiveRequest, CMSO.CHTR.Pipelines, Version=10.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=32f1cdb63bb6ffdb"
>
> Source: "OrderUID Pipeline Component"
>
> Receive Port: "RP.CMSO.CHTR.WebService.SubmitOrder"
>
> URI: D:\Data\CMSO\CHTR\WebService\Retry\SubmitOrder*.xml"
>
> Reason: Error initilalizing AssignOrderUID Execute method.
>
> Exception Details: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> MessageId:  {B1A1A514-CD9E-4164-8767-BF9BB4788EA0}
>
> InstanceID: {892341D0-CC5C-4AF6-A6F2-D8AF49D6E077}

Please be reminded that before we upgraded our BizTalk we can use our system successfully, the error was encountered after the conversion. Can someone help us identifying the root cause of this issue?

Comment: You say "before you upgraded" it worked, but also you say "[we] converted our codes from .Net Framework 2.0 to 4.0, and when we tried to test the newly converted codes..." - so it is not possible for anyone else to tell whether the error is from the upgrade, or from the changes you have made to the code.

Comment: So you did a in-place upgrade first?  And afterwards opened the solution and changed the .Net version and re-deployed?     The issue is with your Custom OrderUID Pipeline Component.  Without that code we can't really help you much.  Have you tried attaching Visual Studio to the Host Instance the pipeline runs in and stepped through the code?

Comment: Yes, I have tried attaching the solution to the host instance but there was no error.

Comment: The only thing we've changed in the codes after migration was the .Net Framework version.